# Eclipse ignores changes to the code, comments or printlines

Tags: eclipse

I'm in eclipse working on a program and when I press run eclipse ignores any new input I try.  I added a System.out.println(); and commented out some lines of code but the print statement didn't print anything to the console and the commented line of code still ran.

Comment: Is Eclipse doing the compiling and launching, and not something like Gradle or Maven?

Comment: Is _Project > Build Automatically_ enabled? Are errors shown in the _Problems_ view?

Comment: I think Eclipse is doing the compiling and launching, I don't think Gradle or Maven is.  Build automatically is enabled.  I don't see a Problems view.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities:

1. As previously implied this looks like a build problem so verify that the target binary has a new date after building. If not debug from that perspective.
2. The debug configuration is not running the class file you just built. If you mucked with the build configuration perhaps you changed the target folder and the debug configuration is referencing the binary in another target folder.